# couldn't install beautiful-docs npm library

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I want to install beautiful-docs library from master source.
https://github.com/beautiful-docs/beautiful-docs

I am trying `npm install -g` command and seems everything is well.
then when i run `bfdocs` command, i am getting following error:

```
module.js:338
  throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module '../lib/command.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
at require (module.js:384:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/beautiful-docs/bin/bfdocs:2:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
```

any idea about this error?

Comment: what platform are you on?

Comment: try reinstalling it, cause bfdocs command is working fine.

Comment: npm --version  2.7.4  node --version
v0.12.2   i tried reinstalling it, but again same error, i also tried with npm docker, again error.

Comment: are you on a Mac? then it might be rights related, i.e. if it works after you install and run it with sudo, then you should change the owner of `/usr/local/bin` I think... or you can try if it works with the current node release 6.2.2